# How to get the text from td node containg both raw text and a link using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm struggling trying to get the text information from a td node containing a link and raw text, as the example bellow.

```
<td>Statue of <a href="/wiki/Camille_Pelletan" title="Camille Pelletan">Camille Pelletan</a></td>
```

What is the best Xpath to extract "Statue of Camille Pelletan" together?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the XPath 1.0 `string` function will return all of the text contained in descendants of the node. (If you pass in a nodeset, it will take only the first node in the set.)

If your example was the entire document, you could use this:

```
string(//td)
```

returns:

> Statue of Camille Pelletan