# How to remove <a> elements from xPath?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm making an applcation in C# with HTMLAgilityPack.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<td colspan="3">
    <a href="tournament_detail.asp?EID=3">The North West Junior Champions League 2016</a>
    <br>
    St Bedes Sports Fields,  Manchester. M21 0TT</td>
</td>
```

I would like to pull out the address, excluding the `<a>` and the `<br />`

I have tried the following:

```
//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[1][not a]
```

[Here is the site I am trying to pull data from](http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp)

I am using HTMLAgilityPack, so I don't believe I can use the string() function (or atleast I get an exception when trying). **Please do not mark this as duplicate, as I am seeking clarification to whether I can use that.**

How can I pull back just the address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the text from td node containg both raw text and a link using Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836090/how-to-get-the-text-from-td-node-containg-both-raw-text-and-a-link-using-xpath)

Comment: @KeithHall Can you give me a relevant example of how that would apply to my code?

I tried `string(//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[1])` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KeithHall To expand, I receive an "Expression must evaluate to a node-set" exception.

Comment: ah sorry, didn't realise HtmlAgilityPack only supports nodes. You can use the `Value` property of the node - `new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp").CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[1]/text()").Value`. If you want to include `The North West Junior Champions League 2016`, leave out the `/text()`

Comment: @KeithHall Thanks Keith, looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding predicate `[not(a)]` would cause the XPath to return only `<td>` element that doesn't have child `<a>`, which isn't the wanted outcome. Instead, add `/text()[normalize-space()]` which will return *direct child, non-empty text node* from the selected `<td>` :

```
var raw = @"<td colspan='3'>
    <a href='tournament_detail.asp?EID=3'>The North West Junior Champions League 2016</a>
    <br>
    St Bedes Sports Fields,  Manchester. M21 0TT</td>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);
var td = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td/text()[normalize-space()]");
Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText.Trim());
```

**output :**

```
St Bedes Sports Fields,  Manchester. M21 0TT
```